# Вытащить все цифры из строки JS

Tags: javascript

Есть определенная строка с условным выводом 11 111 руб.

```
var value =  parseInt(data[key], 10) / 66 + " $";
```

parseInt в данном случае выводит нам только 11, натыкается на пробел и не читает дальше. Задача: вытащить 11 111 и умножить на 65.

Помогите чайнику )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41729633/javascript-parseint-to-remove-spaces-from-a-string/41729670#41729670) уже был дан. Первый результат при поиске в гугле. Учитесь гуглить)

```js
var data = ['11 111 руб', '43 522 руб', '12 641 руб'],
  processed, value;
for (var key = 0; key < data.length; key++) {
  processed = data[key].replace(/ /g, '');
  value =  parseInt(processed, 10) / 66 + " $";  
  console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Я подставил вместо var input = '11 111 руб';  это var input = data[key];  к сожалению не работает http://prntscr.com/nzjizz
вот ссылка на сам сайт http://eldar.cf69638.tmweb.ru/ekonom/kia-rio-2011

Comment: на сколько я понимаю проблема в data[key] , его нужно как-то иначе туда вписать

Comment: Я увидел, что вы изменили сообщение, но мне нужно вставлять не 11 111, а вот такой массив data[key], он цены генерирует на странице товара

Comment: Подправил, чтоб вам было наглядней. Если key переменная - вероятно у вас идет перебор массива, если key это название ключа - возьмите его в кавычки

Comment: Надеюсь с перебором более доступно?))

Comment: var data = data['key'];   var data = data["key"]; оба варианта не срабатывают http://prntscr.com/nzjnpc

Comment: Вы в примере выше указываете ['11 111 руб', '43 522 руб', '12 641 руб'], проблема в том, что у меня в переменной выводится data[key], там нету цифр, он как-то подтягивает цены из выпадающего списка virtuemart

Comment: И как я понимаю, нужно это полученное число порезать чтобы оставались только цифры. третий день ковыряюсь уже...

Comment: Так поднимитесь по коду, найдите data. Я не вижу вашего кода и я не телепат. Если у вас попадает data[key] значит это перебор data, где key это индекс итерации, соответственно data это массив с данными. Как на обычном переборе можно ковыряться третий день?

Comment: по причине того, что я не знаю js )  вот ссылка на js файл http://eldar.cf69638.tmweb.ru/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmpricesru.js?vmver=9cfc611b . помогите пожалуйста

Comment: как же вставить data[key] в var data = чтобы оно сработало?

Comment: Как я и предположил это перебор массива. Вам нужно убрать пробы processed = data[key].replace(/ /g, ''); и уже processed подставлять в parseInt, а именно var value =  parseInt(processed, 10) / 66 + " $"; А вообще это не код, а полная жесть

Comment: Вы могли бы готовое решение опубликовать? Я реально не понимаю что делать с вашей инструкцией...

Comment: перепробовал все варианты которые приходят в голову, и так и сяк - не срабатывает...

Comment: еще на реплейс жалуется Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Comment: Если делать вашим перебором, то в key попадает уже значение, а не индекс как в моем примере.

Comment: как же быть? как обработать это значение и еще умножить на другую цифру?

Comment: Я написал в ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/990980/339835 . В вашем файле в каждой пятой строчке ошибка. Если вы еще и js не знаете, до пенсии этот код ковырять будете.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так, разбив регуляркой `/\D/` это обозначает "любой символ не число"

```js
var data = {rub:"11 111 руб"};
var key = "rub"
var usd_rub = 66;
var value = (+data[key].split(/\D/).join('')/usd_rub).toFixed(2) + ' $'
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Вы могли бы мне конкретно под мой код дать точный вариант? я не понимаю в этом... http://prntscr.com/nzjh16

Comment: @Риад изменил ответ

Comment: в комментарии ниже мы попробовали много вариантов. нам нельзя вставлять какое-то определенное значение в  var data, т.к. data[key] генерируется динамически

Comment: @Риад и как это влияет, не пойму?

Comment: я сам не понимаю. посмотрите пожалуйста сам скрипт http://eldar.cf69638.tmweb.ru/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/vmpricesru.js?vmver=9cfc611b  146 строка

Comment: на сайте стоит магазин виртумарт. и этот скрипт при выборе какого-то из вариантов выпадающего списка делает ajax обновление

Comment: может быть как-то можно у массива удалить все буквы и пробелы? и не шаманить с этой переменной data[key]

Comment: http://eldar.cf69638.tmweb.ru/ekonom/kia-rio-2011

Comment: как же вставить data[key] в var data = чтобы оно сработало?

Answer (score 0):

В ответ на комментарий

```js
//Предположим, что в data вам пришли следующие данные
var data = ['11 111 руб', '43 522 руб', '12 641 руб']; // Это в код вставлять не нужно, data у вас пришла ответом на запрос

for (var key of data) {
  var processed = key.replace(/ /g, '');
  var value = parseInt(processed, 10) / 66 + " $";
  
  console.log(value) // это тоже в кон не пишем
  //Дальше ваш код
}
```

Comment: вставил код вот так http://prntscr.com/nzkn7o и получил NaN http://prntscr.com/nzkngn

Comment: Измени for (var key in data) на for (var key of data)

Comment: изменил, теперь ошибочка Uncaught TypeError: data is not iterable

Comment: Выбрось тот код на свалку. Там ошибка на ошибке

Comment: уже почти получилось, только NaN осталось выпилить)

Comment: куда копать чтобы убрать NaN?